# "bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format" while running vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am taking a course on Udacity that requires me to set up a virtual machine on my system. I have already downloaded and installed Virtual Box and Vagrant. When I try to run the command `vagrant up`, I get this error:
[image]

Could anyone please explain what might be going wrong?

I am working on my office laptop so I cannot change the firewall settings. They are controlled by McAfee. Also, the firewall has been turned off by McAfee to the best of my knowledge. I tried searching a lot but couldn't come up with a solution to this.

Comment: most probably your download is not complete and the zip file is corrupted - you can try another time. btw whats your vagrant version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I researched more about this and was finally able to find something. This issue comes up when vagrant doesn't have folder permission. Sometimes Cygwin shell in Windows doesn't get permission to write or create a new folder.

I followed their [github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3869). This is what made it work for me:

1. Rename `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gnuwin32\bin\bsdtar.exe` to
   something like `bsdtar_backup.exe` (or temporarily move it)
2. In that same directory, create `bsdtar.bat` with this content:

   @ECHO OFF

   "%~dp0....\mingw\bin\bsdtar.exe" %*

This will result in Vagrant using the mingw binary, without you having to dive into some code. After these two steps, try adding a box.